# jquery basic of dollar sign - named vs anonymous

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of interview questions

1. What is the different between `$(function(){});` and `$(document).ready(function(){});`
2. What is the difference between `$(function(){});` and `var func=function(){};` How are each of them called?
3. Given the following script

   ```
   <script language="javascript">
   $(function()
   {
      var id=$("cssID");
      //do something with your id
      //your event to be added here
   });
   </script>
   ```

   How can you add an event, say, `onmouseout` that will work on the `id`?

Here are my answers:

1. They are the same, both are meant to run when the page document finishes loading
2. The first one is called automatically while the second one will be called via named reference; that is `func.called()`, for example.
3. Something like this:

   ```
   $(function()
   {
       var id=$("cssID");
       //do something with your id
       //Oki
       id.onmouseout
       (function(){
         //do something
       });
   });
   ```

However my professor says I was wrong in all three. she explained things I am unsure and didn't dare to ask, she was mad about me. What are the correct answers and why are mine wrong?

Comment: Why the -1? This seemed like a legitimate question with effort put in.

Comment: @arxanas: -1 because it's not one question and is another "is this right" question that isn't really useful and can easily be determined on one's own.

Answer (score 1):

These are the different types of Document Ready functions typically used in jQuery (aka jQuery DOM Ready). A lot of developers seem to use them without really knowing why. So I will try to explain why you might choose one version over another. Think of the document ready function as a self-executing function which fires after the page elements have loaded.

See [Where to Declare Your jQuery Functions](http://jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/declare-jquery-function/) for more information on how to use the Document Ready Functions.

**Document Ready Example 1**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //do jQuery stuff when DOM is ready
});
```

**Document Ready Example 2**

```
$(function(){ 
    //jQuery code here 
});
```

*This is equivalent to example 1… they literally mean the same thing.*

**Document Ready Example 3**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //do jQuery stuff when DOM is ready
});
```

**Document Ready Example 4**

```
(function($) { 
    // code using $ as alias to jQuery
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

**Document Ready Example 5**

```
$(window).load(function(){  
     //initialize after images are loaded  
});
```

**[Here](http://www.jquery4u.com/dom-modification/types-document-ready/)** is the link for you to refer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between:

```
$(functionValue);
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(functionValue);
```

So your professor is wrong there. The second example is completely different. One of them runs on document ready and requires jQuery; the other one is just a function literal assigned to a JavaScript variable.

As for the third one, you'd probably do it with `on`. `onmouseover` is correct if you use `get`, but not really the best way of going about things, and you *definitely* wouldn't call it like you're doing there - that's completely incorrect.

```
id.on('mouseout', yourHandler);
```

or

```
id.mouseout(yourHandler);
```

Comment: Regarding the mouseover, not sure what you mean by `get`, but the question asked specifically about onmouseout rather than onmouseover. With jQuery you use `.mouseout` not `.onmouseout` so  `id.mouseout(yourHandler)` is one correct way and `id.on('mouseout',yourHandler)` is another correct way.

Comment: @nnnnnn: `.get()` would get you an element, so `.get().onmouseout = *whatever*` is what I meant. Also, thanks, fixed.

Comment: Oh, right, `.get()`, sorry, of course you are right. That method completely slipped my mind when I saw `get`without the parentheses, probably because I never use it (I would use `id[i]` rather than `id.get(i)`).

Answer (score 0):

> *1. They are the same, both are meant to run when the page document finishes loading*

This is half right. They *are* the same, the first is just a shortcut way to write the second, but they don't run when the document finishes loading, they run when the DOM is ready (at which time some resources such as images might still be loading).

> *2. The first one is called automatically while the second one will be called via named reference; that is `func.called()`, for example.*

Again half right. In the first one the anonymous function will be called automatically when the DOM is ready as per question 1. The second example can be called with `func()`. You wouldn't have the `.called` part in there. Or you can pass `func` as a parameter, e.g., as `$(document).ready(func)`.

> Q3
> `var id=$("cssID");`
>
> *How can you add an event, say, `onmouseout` that will work on the `id`?*

`$("cssID")` creates a jQuery object that will contain zero or more elements depending on how many matched the `"cssID"` selector. The `id` variable references that jQuery object. If the question is how to assign an event handler to those matching elements you'd do this:

```
id.mouseout(function() { /* some code */. });
// OR
id.on("mouseout", function() { /* some code */ });
```

When processing events with jQuery you don't use "on" in the event names, so it's "mouseout" not "onmouseout".

So your answer to 3 was *nearly* right.

(Note though that `"cssID"` is a selector that won't actually match any elements unless you have `<cssID>` tags in your document...)